# Not able to get currently logged user in symfony2 controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this code in controller

```
public function newAction()
    {
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in
>   /home/xxxxx/Acme/UserBundle/Controller/UserController.php on line 86

Comment: Please, attach your `security.yml` and route of your action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that your security context was not populated with token. It happens, when route to your action is not behind the firewall.

You should check your firewall pattern in `security.yml`

Comment: I am using AuthenticationHandler as given in SF2 doc. I used var_dump() to check if I get data there...                       `public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    var_dump($user);exit;                                                      }`.  I am getting full user object here. But after authentication, in controller, I am getting *Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in* error.

Comment: It was indeed that. Changed my routing.yml and it instantly worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Make Sure you are logged in using the Symfony debug bar. If you can see there as logged then it should work ok
2. Also have a look if that path is behind firewall. If its not even though You are logged but you will not get the user

Comment: For my application setup, 1st point is satisfied. As far as 2nd point is concerned, what does "Behind the firewall" mean? I don't write any pattern in security.yml to restrict the route. Then, why I am not able to access **$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();** from controller? I am using Handler to authenticate user as given in SF2 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. My mistake was the following:

security.yml

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I had to change the controller where I was having the error from this:

*routing.yml (BAD)*

```
admin_bets:
    resource: "@adminBundle/Resources/config/routing/bets.yml"
    prefix:   /bets
```

to this:

*routing.yml (GOOD)*

```
admin_bets:
    resource: "@adminBundle/Resources/config/routing/bets.yml"
    prefix:   /admin/bets
```